MySQL Query Slow on Staging Instance but Fast on Local - Performance Issue
Description:
I'm facing a performance issue with a MySQL query that runs efficiently on my local machine (0.02 seconds) but takes a significantly longer time to execute on the staging environment. The execution time on staging varies randomly; sometimes, it takes around 4 seconds, and other times it exceeds 10 seconds.
Sample Query:
SELECT 
    table1.qid,
    table1.original_text,
    table1.resolved_text,
    table1.resolved_values
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2
    ON table_1.id = table_2.variation_id
WHERE table_2.users_id = 6
    AND table_1.qid = 201;

CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    qid int NOT NULL, 
    original_text text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, 
    resolved_text text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, 
    resolved_values json DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    KEY qid_index (qid), 
    KEY original_text_index (original_text(256)),
    KEY resolved_text_index (resolved_text(256))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4644665
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE table_2 (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    users_id int NOT NULL, 
    variation_id int NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    KEY uid_index (users_id), 
    KEY var_index (variation_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=437879832
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Context:

I need to run this query for different users_id values in a loop using Python and SQLAlchemy.
The execution time is inconsistent; it varies randomly when running the query multiple times on staging.
I've used the EXPLAIN statement to analyze the query, and it seems to be using the appropriate indexes:

EXPLAIN Output:
1   SIMPLE  table_1     NULL  ref  PRIMARY,qid_index  qid_index  4  const           1    100.00  NULL
1   SIMPLE  table_2     NULL  ref  uid_index,var_index  var_index  4  table_1.id  133  0.04  Using where


Observations:

The query performs well on the local environment, but it becomes slow on the staging server.
Profiling indicates that the executing phase is consuming most of the time.
A slight variation of this query without the qid filter runs quickly on the staging environment:

SELECT 
    table1.qid,
    table1.original_text,
    table1.resolved_text,
    table1.resolved_values
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2
    ON table_1.id = table_2.variation_id
WHERE table_2.users_id = 6;


Additional Information:

Both table_1 and table_2 have indexes on the columns used in the JOIN and WHERE clauses.
The number of rows expected to be scanned, as indicated by EXPLAIN, seems reasonable.
I've verified that the staging instance has sufficient resources, and there's no obvious resource contention.

Questions:

What could cause the query to perform inconsistently on the staging environment?
Why would the execution time vary so much for the same query?
Why does adding the additional qid filter cause such a drastic difference in performance?
Are there any specific server configurations, MySQL settings, or environmental factors that could affect this behavior?

Note: When I run the query directly via phpmyadmin or via any mysql client, then runs quickly.
I'm looking for insights or suggestions on how to further diagnose and resolve this issue. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Added all the details above

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for each table.

CREATE TABLE table_1 (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
qid int NOT NULL,
original_text text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
resolved_text text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
resolved_values json DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY qid_index (qid),
KEY original_text_index (original_text(256)),
KEY resolved_text_index (resolved_text(256))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4644665 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE table_2 (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
users_id int NOT NULL,
variation_id int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY uid_index (users_id),
KEY var_index (variation_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=437879832 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

@RickJames Added both tables create table syntax above. Due to length constraints, added as separate comments.

These may help performace:
table_1:  INDEX(qid, id)
table_2:  INDEX(users_id, variation_id)

If table_2 is many-to-many, get rid of `id and have:
PRIMARY KEY(users_id, variation_id)
INDEX(variation_id, users_id)

Index prefixing ((users_id, variation_id))  is rarely useful.
If the two machines do not have the same number of rows, that may lead to explaining why there is a difference.
ANALYZE TABLE may be helpful, but this is unlikely.
